# Unit test conditional statements using environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, pytest-mock, parameterized-unit-test

I have a source file `util.py` and there I have below one, where `day` is an AWS lambda environment variable.

```py
import os

day = os.getenv("DAY")

def get_day_code():
    if day == "Monday":
        return "M"
    if day == "Tuesday":
        return "T"
    if day == "Wednesday":
        return "W"
```

I need to write a unit test for this function. I tried using pytest paramaterise, but nothing works. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) returns `None`, if no environment variable with the provided name is found, you don't need to mock that function. Instead, you can simply patch the global variable `day` during your tests.

[`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) can be used in the form of a context manager. That way you can easily probe every branch of your function in a loop.

Assuming your code resides in a module named `util`, here is a working example test module:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from . import util


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_get_day_code(self) -> None:
        day_map = {
            "Monday": "M",
            "Tuesday": "T",
            "Wednesday": "W",
        }
        for day, expected_output in day_map.items():
            with patch.object(util, "day", new=day):
                self.assertEqual(expected_output, util.get_day_code())
```

---

If you want to use `pytest`, you can also inject temporary environment variables using [`monkeypatch.setenv`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/monkeypatch.html), but I would argue that there again directly patching the `day` variable is the easier route to take. The test should look essentially the same as demonstrated above.